# iText 2.1.7 Read security parameters - everytime zero value

Tags: security, itext

i am trying to read my pdf with permissions and itext library 2.1.7 with programming language java. If I call "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PDFReader.getPermissions()" I get everytime 0 return value.

How can I get permissions which are shown in Adobe PDF Reader like "Signing Documents"?

Kind regards

Comment: The permission to sign documents can only be set by Reader-enabling a document. Reader-enabling can only be done with Adobe software. It would be illegal to Reader-enable a PDF using software that isn't owned by Adobe. By the way: there are also legal issues with iText 2.1.7. If you're using that obsolete, unsupported, discontinued version, you should upgrade.

Comment: Is it an error that i cant read any permission (I dont think of the reader-enable Permissions)? allow-printing, etc.

Comment: I don't know for 2.1.7: we have removed all copies of that version (and so should you).

Comment: I think nis90 is not talking about the adobe proprietary 'reader-enabled' stuff but about the standard PDF permissions which also contains a property called 'signing' (and printing etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably your document doesn't have any permission set - in this case 0 is returned (but without the original PDF it is difficult to tell).

The source of the problem is most likely the misleading adobe reader behavior when showing permissions:

If you open your PDF in the adobe reader and look at the File\Property\Security tab and the security method is 'no security' then there are no permissions defined. The adobe **reader** however will still show certain permissions as 'not allowed' which is due to the fact that the reader itself doesn't have the ability to do e.g. 'document assembly' or 'page extraction'. If you open that PDF with the adobe acrobat all permissions will appear as 'allowed' which is the standard if no permissions are defined.

To test that your code is working open the following [PDF](https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/blob/master/resources/pdfs/hello_encrypted.pdf).

```
    InputStream fis = FileInputStream("encryption_encrypted.pdf");
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fis,"World".getBytes());

    int permissions = reader.getPermissions();
    System.out.println(permissions);
    String verbose = PdfEncryptor.getPermissionsVerbose(permissions);
    System.out.println(verbose);
```