# How to read the permissions of an encrypted PDF file?

Tags: java, itext

I am reading PDF files with iText v7 and I am detecting encrypted files as follows:

```java
try (final PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
     PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    System.out.println("encrypted = " + pdfReader.isEncrypted());
}
```

I would like to know which individual permissions are allowed on the PDF files (printing, copy text, modify content, modify annotations).

I know that the `getPermissions` method should return the permissions read from the file but I haven't managed to check the relevant flags, i.e. the following code does not yeld the correct results:

```java
final long perm = - pdfReader.getPermissions();
if ((perm & EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING) == EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING) {
    System.out.println("Allow printing");
}
```

The documentation I have found is a bit terse on the subject, mainly detailng how to create an encrypted file with specific permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, inspired by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131830/itext-2-1-7-read-security-parameters-everytime-zero-value).

Use the `PdfEncryptor` class to decode the permission flags packed in the `long` returned by `PdfReader.getPermissions` method:

```java
final int perm = (int) pdfReader.getPermissions();
if (PdfEncryptor.isDegradedPrintingAllowed(perm)) {
    System.out.println("Allow degraded printing";
}
```

The only anomaly found in the API is that `getPermissions` returns `long` while the `PdfEncryptor` methods take `int` as an argument.